# How to Display a Loading Status in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm making an Angular app and I'd love for it to tell the user how long its taking for their information to download via an API.

Basically I'm doing this right now:

```
app.controller('GlossaryCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://example.com/api/v1/glossary',
    })
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.glossary = data;
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        $scope.glossary = [
            {"title": "Error:",
             "description": "Please ensure you are connected to the internet or try again in a few minutes."}
        ];
    });
});
```

Now, while the glossary is being downloaded, is there a way for me to get the length to which it has downloaded? This way I can create a status bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that all JSON data is transferred as text and parsed as JSON on the client side. There's not really a way for you to know before the JSON document is finished how many total items there are (or how many you've received so far).

You may be able to work out how to wire up [xhr progress events](http://www.w3.org/TR/progress-events/), however that's still an  [outstanding issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1934) for angular.

Probably the easiest thing to do would be to show an animated gif.  If you're using angular-ui/bootstrap, you could display an animated progress bar. The [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/progressbar) has plenty of examples.

Comment: So you can use a flag `$scope.loaded` on each callback and set `ng-if="!loaded"` on the progress bar. ng-if adds or removes the dom element based on the expression instead of just hiding or showing.